# Problems with intersection complement demonstration

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading a book about set theory and it have this preposition:

Let B and B' be subsets of A, then:

$\complement_A(B \cup B') = \complement_A(B) \cap \complement_A(B')$

and he does the proof this way:

(1) $x \in \complement_A(B\cup B') \rightarrow x\notin B \cup B'$

(2)$ \rightarrow x \notin B$ and $x \notin B'$

(3) $\rightarrow x \in \complement_A(B) \cap \complement_A(B')$

Okay, I can understend how (2) implies on (3) but no how (1) implies on (2)

to be more specific, how  $ x\notin B \cup B'$ implie on this $ x \notin B$ and $x \notin B'$.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $C_A$??

Comment: when $B \subset  A$ you have $C_A(B) = A - B$

Comment: There is a \complement in latex... $\complement_A(B)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The union $B \cup B'$ is indicated in yellow. So if  $x\notin B \cup B'$ then $x\notin B$ and $x\notin B'$.

Answer (score 1):

The missing logical step is
$$x\not\in B\cup B^\prime \Leftrightarrow \lnot (x \in B\cup B^\prime)\Leftrightarrow \lnot (x \in B \text{ or } x \in B^\prime)\Leftrightarrow \lnot (x \in B) \text{ and } \lnot (x\in B^\prime)$$