# Element In A Union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This maybe trivial, but I just want to be sure.

$$x\not \in A\cup B\iff x\not \in A \wedge x\not \in B$$ Or $$x\not \in A \vee x\not \in B$$

Comment: See this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2506436/problems-with-intersection-complement-demonstration/2506457#2506457

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \in A\cup B \iff x\in A \lor x\in B$.

Hence, taking the negation of both sides

$x\notin A\cup B \iff \neg(x\in A \lor x\in B)$ iff $x\notin A \land x\notin B$.

Answer (score 1):

From simple logic: if $x \not \in A \cup B$, $x$ is not in a set of elements from $A$ or $B$ -- hence not in $A$ and not in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is correct: DeMorgan's is key here.

$\begin{align}x \notin (A\cup B) &\iff \lnot (x \in A\cup B)\tag{1. definition}\\ \\ 
& \iff  \lnot(x \in A \lor x\in B) \tag{2. definition of set union} \\ \\  & \iff \lnot(x\in A) \land \lnot(x\in B)\tag{3. DeMoran's Law}\\ \\ &\iff x \notin A \land x \notin B \tag{4. definition}\end{align}$